# Replacing numbers in a long list by other numbers

Tags: bash, loops, sed

I am trying to change numbers in a long list by other numbers. For example,

```
cat inputfile.txt
A 254 B 456 C 546
D 548 E 548 F 458

A 244 B 416 C 566
D 148 E 558 F 428
```

And I want to change B's value by adding a percentage on it. For example I want to increase the B in the first array by 3% and b in the next one by 2 % as following:

```
 cat inputfile.txt
A 254 B 469.68 C 546
D 548 E 548 F 458

A 244 B 424.32 C 566
D 148 E 558 F 428
```

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
 a=(456  416)
b= (469.68 424.32)
for i in ${a[@]};
for j in ${b[@]}; do
sed -i -- "s/${i}/${j}" inputfile.txt
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems.

```
cat inputfile.txt
A 254 B 456 C 546
D 548 E 548 F 458

A 244 B 416 C 566
D 148 E 558 F 428

a=(456  416)
b= (469.68 424.32)
for i in ${a[@]};
for j in ${b[@]}; do
sed -i -- "s/${i}/${j}" inputfile.txt
done
```

a) 
Your assignment to b fails. There is no space allowed around assignment.

b) The substitution pattern isn't closed:

```
sed -i -- "s/${i}/${j}/" inputfile.txt
```

c) Now it should run with values not empty, but this will try to replace 456 with 469.68 and then with 424.32. This can't work, since the value is already changed to 469.68. Then it will try to change every 416 with both values.

```
a=(456  416)
b=(469.68 424.32)
for i in ${a[@]};
for j in ${b[@]}; do
  sed "s/${i}/${j}/" inputfile.txt
done
```

You have two corresponding values which need to be in sync, because you want to replace the first by the second. So you have to iterate once, and by the index:

```
max=${#a[@]}
for i in $(seq 0 $((max - 1))); do
  sed "s/${a[$i]}/${b[$i]}/" inputfile.txt
done
```

I removed the -i for testing from sed.

The last problem is, that there might be number collisions, for example replacing 456 in 1456 with 469.68 or 416 in 416.02 with 424.32.

To prevent this from happening we can put a blank before the number to match and a boundary for matching blank or line end in the end:

```
  sed "s/ ${a[$i]}\b/ ${b[$i]}/" inputfile.txt
```

The \b-notation has the advantage (over [ $]) that we don't need to catch it, to push it back in the values, it is non-consuming.

```
a=(456  416)
b=(469.68 424.32)
max=${#a[@]}
for i in $(seq 0 $((max - 1))); do
  sed -i "s/ ${a[$i]}\b/ ${b[$i]}/" inputfile.txt
done
```

I don't know the source of your a and b values - maybe my following reasoning doesn't apply, but the storage of as and bs in arrays seems not optimal. They have to be of same length but aren't guaranteed to be. You may test it, but if one value gets lost, it's hard to find out where it was, to remove the corresponding b-value.

Not combining all originals and all replacements, binding pairs seems the better idea:

```
a=(456 469.68)
b=(416 424.32)
```

But that's not far from the final sed-expression, which would be:

```
a="s/ 456\b/ 469.68/"
b="s/ 416\b/ 424.32/"
```

Now that's a bit more verbose, but we save the loop complete:

```
  sed -i "${a};${b}" inputfile.txt
```

and the input file has only to be read once, and now can be testet without -i in complete.

If you happen to have mass data, you can just generate a file like that:

```
s/ 456\b/ 469.68/
s/ 416\b/ 424.32/
```

and name it numcorrect.sed, and call it by:

```
sed -f numcorrect.sed inputfile.txt
```

Comment: I tried it on my long file but it only changed the first match and it kept everything else as it is.  Do you have any idea why is that hapenning?

Comment: I removed the -i from the sed command, to keep the testing file intact. Only later, at the last steps, I put it back in. Are you using the latest suggestion with a .sed-file or which one?

Comment: awesome. When I removed -i it works fine on the command screen but not inside the file. I added > outputfile but didn't change in it.

Comment: Depending on whether you use a for loop, or for example the version shortly before the end, the one without a sedfile, each command is issued on the given input file name, so the last command will see the fresh inputfile, modify it, and only then the outfile is written. With an -i in each step, this is prevented (but less convenient for testing). With a sedfile, this won't happen, since the writing only takes place after processing the whole sedfile.

Comment: Similarly, a command like `sed 'cmd1;cmd2;cmd3;cmd4;' infile > outfile` will process all commands before writing, but here as there the intermediate changes don't get lost, but iteratively applied, so in both cases the order of commands matters.

Comment: I mean first one and last one only changed out of 260.

Comment: If our matrix changed from 2X1 to 3X1, you will notice that only the first one and last one will change. The one in the middle won't change. Thanks a lot for your helpful comments and script :)

Comment: Which matrix? The input is 4x3, imho, and the transformation rule is 2x2. I still don't know, which variant you used. The redirection to an outfile only works, if you process all changes in one sed call - not in a loop, since each command in the loop will see the virgin input and the last invocation will overwrite the outfile. Maybe the first line change is from a former change? First and last line (same value?) seems suspicious.

Comment: In my list of 260, I used the same script you provided and it only changes when i specified the array. For example if I used same one you provided it only changes the first and the last array "not matrix, sorry" then if I changed the script from $((max - 1)) to $((max - 25)) it will change the 25th line from the bottom. How to let them all change without one-by-one?

Comment: (when will the link occur, to discuss it in chat?) - Your list of 260 is 260 pairs of values to change?  So what has been a=(456  416) in the question will now be 260 values, and 260 in b? - Ah, I found a bug! It has to be command substitution: Not: `for i in seq 0 $((max - 1)); do` but `for i in $(seq 0 $((max - 1))); do` - sorry. Curious, that it didn't spit out an ugly error message and worked for 2 values. I'm correcting the answer now.